# Spring @Schedular executes twice in my code

Tags: java, spring

I have given my code below of spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml, it produces schedular execution twice. I don`t know why?

My Code is below:

```
 <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="app" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/webjars/**"  location="/webjars/" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <task:annotation-driven />
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
   <bean id="schedularController" class="app.controllers.schedularController" >


    <task:scheduled-tasks>
        <task:scheduled ref="schedularController" method="Scheduler" cron="${cron}" ></task:scheduled>
    </task:scheduled-tasks>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
```

and in java class Code is like:

```
@Component
public class schedularController {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(schedularController.class.getName());
    //Code For schedular
    private static final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

    public void Scheduler(){            
            System.out.println("The time is now {}"+ dateFormat.format(new Date()));
}
}
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSJeZ.png)

Comment: Paste cron expression

Comment: task executed twice may be because the bean loaded twice，refer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20880145/scheduled-task-executed-twice) to find some help.

Comment: @TongChen Good point @Balram Kumar Remove `@Component` annotation from your class, and check how it behave.

Comment: If it executes twice, the configuration is loaded twice. Make sure your `ContextLOaderListener` doesn’t load this XML file. Ifyou do both this and your `DispatcherServlet` will load the configuration and start a scheduler. Basically you are running your whole application twice that way.

Comment: Ya u r right it loads the entire application twice, how can I separate the code for ContextLoader and DispatchedServlet ?